# Can I set up arbitrary commands in an Eclipse Java project run configuration?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a Java Eclipse project, but I don't run it from the command line using java.exe. Instead I run it through a python script that runs the java.

What I'd like to do is run this when I hit the 'Run' button in eclipse and see the output in Eclipse's console window. Unfortunately the available run configuration options available are a little too restrictive and don't seem to allow for this arbitrary 'run anything you like' configuration.

Is this possible? Are there any eclipse plugins that add this kind of configuration option?

I realise I'd probably lose debugger support, but this is not an issue for me.

Comment: FYI: You can still use the debugger if you configure the right launch params in your Python script and then use Java remote debugging.

Comment: @McDowell: I was writing that in my answer as you were writing the comment ;) Good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could run it through an "external Tools Configuration": it can call any script/command you like, even if that script launches itself your Java program.

[image]
<sub>(source: [abdevelopment.ca](http://www.abdevelopment.ca/system/files/images/New%20External%20Tools%20Configuration.preview.png))</sub>

Then, once it is launched, you can initiate a remote debug session, provided your script did launch the Java program with the right options

```
-Djava.compiler=NONE -Xnoagent -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

[alt text http://www.nakov.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/eclipse-remote-debug-configuration.png](http://www.nakov.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/eclipse-remote-debug-configuration.png)

Comment: You know I've looked at that button for years and it's never occurred to me to press it. Thanks :)